# Selenium Python click a Button without ID

Tags: python, selenium

I have a Button:

```
<button type="button" class="Buttonstyled__StyledButton-sc-140xkaw-1 bbPePk css-1n4k82t">Zum Warenkorb</button>
```

I want to click this Button but I don't have the id are there other ways?

I am learning Selenium maybe someone could answer me that question it would be very nice. Thank you!

Comment: Have a look here: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html

Answer (score 1):

You can click using class name, like this:

1. Select

   ```
   button = driver.find_element_by_class_name('Buttonstyled__StyledButton-sc-140xkaw-1 bbPePk css-1n4k82t')
   ```
2. Execute:

`button.click()`

In this example, 'driver' is an instance of selenium using Firefox Web driver

Selenium docs can be helpful: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html

Answer (score 0):

You can actually look for the button class to find it (but it returns a list of **all** of the elements with that class since classes aren't unique):

```py
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.theClass')
```

Details can be found here https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find_elements_by_css_selector-driver-method-selenium-python/, but assuming it's the first one in the page you can use:

```py
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.theClass')[0]
```

In your case it would be:

```py
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".Buttonstyled__StyledButton-sc-140xkaw-1")[0]
```

Assuming it is the first one in the page. If it's not the first one with that class then you will have to choose which one in the list returned by the method is the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium can locate elements based not only on their id values.
Locator can be based on any unique tag name, any element attribute and any relation to some other elements.
In this particular case it looks that your element contains unique text.
If so, you can locate it by XPath based on that text as following:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//button[text()="Zum Warenkorb"]').click()
```

You should also add some wait / delay before accessing this element to let the element be fully loaded before you going to click on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can construct a robust `xpath` like this :

```
//button[contains(@class,'Buttonstyled__StyledButton') and text()='Zum Warenkorb']
```

and then use it like this :

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(@class,'Buttonstyled__StyledButton') and text()='Zum Warenkorb']").click()
```

or if it requires explicit wait then :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 50)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(@class,'Buttonstyled__StyledButton') and text()='Zum Warenkorb']"))).click()
```